# Run-Time error '1004' Unable to get the pivot table properties of the work sheet class

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need to create Pivot Table but I am trying to add Row Field But I am getting error as "Run-Time error '1004' Unable to get the pivot table properties of the work sheet class"

```
On Error Resume Next
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            WS.Range(PT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next PT
    Next WS
Set Pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ZFIGLABACUS")
 ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "FBL5N!R1C1:R30000C14", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="SUMMARY!R3C9", TableName:="ZFIGLABACUS", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Select


    Pvt.PivotFields("G/L Account").Orientation = xlRowField
```

I am unable to add the Row fields to the pivot where am i getting wrong help me out

Comment: You are deleting all Pivot-Tables from all worksheets, when you re-create the Pivot-Table, you don't use `Set Pvt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create...` , so you are getting an error on the following line

Comment: So what is can i do now to eliminate the error should i need to delete the particular previous pivot or any thing else.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You are deleting all Pivot-Tables, and then re-creating them, why ?

Comment: Because I need pivot in same sheet but Previous pivot should delete and now i updated codes please verify even after it is not picking

Comment: Why you need a new Pivot ? If just the Data Source Range has changed, there is a better solution

Comment: I never tried Pivot in VBA so i don't have any idea, Like how it works First Pivot we need to create and then next need to change data source or like how it works

Comment: Can you tell me what sheet is the source data? What range ? And where do you want to place your Pivot-Table ?

Comment: source data is worksheet FBL5N and set range till R1C1:R30000C14, pivot table will be in sheet SUMMARY

Comment: Just a quick look.  Try to move `Set Pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ZFIGLABACUS")` just before `Sheets("SUMMARY").Select` and see if that works.

Comment: @Nithin see my answer and code below

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoPivotTable()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim SrcData As Range
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

'-- Determine the data range you want to pivot --
' Set the Worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FBL5N")
Set SrcData = Sht.Range("A1:M30000")

' Set the Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

' Set the Worksheet object where the Pivot Table will be placed
Set PvtSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")

On Error Resume Next
'Set the pivot table object
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("ZFIGLABACUS") ' check if Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)
On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then '<-- Pivot Table not created >> create it
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "SUMMARY" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("I3"), TableName:="ZFIGLABACUS")
    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("G/L Account")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With

Else ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```